# Too big nested arrays causes segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm running into a problem, I need to do some big data crunching and creating too big arrays seems to cause `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Here is a replication of the problem :

```
int main() {
struct { char a[2000][12] } b[2000];
return 0; }
```

I'm using Archlinux 64 bits, `cc` as a compiler, `ulimit -s` returns `8192` which is strange since I have 24GB of RAM. Any idea how to fix the problem ? I think it has to do with `stack` and `heap` but I have no idea what those are.

Comment: It's Stack Overflow!

Comment: @KirillBulygin This site has achieved its purpose and will shut down.

Comment: You need to allocate from the heap.  Stack size is usually limited to 1MB or so.  Read up on malloc/free.

Comment: Does your data always requires this big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are trying to allocate 2000*12*2000/1024 = 46875 KB on the stack but allow to use only 8192 KB. A quick fix is to set `ulimit -s 50000`.

In short about `stack` and `heap`: stack is a private memory of each function call (that's where the contents of function variables reside, i.e. scalar values, addresses and so on), and heap is a public memory with generally less strict limits (see e.g. `malloc(3)`).

Comment: What would result in the faster program : increasing the stack size or doing some kind of dynamic memory allocation ?

Comment: In terms of speed these ways are practically the same, but allocating large memory on stack is just wrong, partly because there is a chance to incidentally use the memory after the function call ends (and the memory contents is to be damaged by other data), also because you would have to call `ulimit(1)` or `ulimit(2)` to extend the stack size (and also on some non-desktop architectures it's just impossible to have large stack).

Answer (score 1):

```
ulimit -s
```

doesn't return the total RAM size. It returns just the available stack size that the current shell has (and all the processes it can create). So, the available RAM size doesn't matter.

You can increase it using `ulimit -s unlimited`. But I'd suggest using dynamic memory allocation for such large arrays instead as your array size is ~48MB and you can easily run into trouble if that's not unavailable on stack, mainly because "stack allocation" failure is difficult to detect.

Answer (score 1):

Your using stack memory by declaring your array with a local variable. Use your heap with memory allocation:

```
typedef struct {
    char a[2000][12];
} bigArray;

int main(void) {
    bigArray *array;
    array = (bigArray*)malloc(2000 * sizeof(bigArray));

    // Do stuff with array here

    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```